Using Tailwinds with Parcel and Babel - livereload trouble
Wondering if anyone can please help me understand, I am trying to use tailwinds along with parcel bundler but am having a hard time getting it running nicely and I assume it has to do with the compiling being needing to be done each time.
When I run the below dev script the app launches fine with changes, but if I make changes to the html the app crashes because it is unbinding if I update some css classes hot reload work, others not. Any assistance would be much appreciated. Ive tried using live server using script tw then launching live server too but then the css updates but none of my components load in. Any words of advice?
error when editing html after launching dev script
node:fs:1884
  binding.unlink(path);
          ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'C:\xampp\htdocs\FrontendFlow\development\index.html.22816.a'
    at Object.unlinkSync (node:fs:1884:11)
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\FrontendFlow\node_modules\@parcel\fs\lib\index.js:1024:83)  
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:634:26)

package.json
   {
"name": "frontendflow",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
  "tw": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/css/style.css -p 3000 --watch",
  "dev": "rm -rf ./development && rm -rf ./.parcel-cache && npx prettier --write **/*.html && npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/css/style.css && parcel public/index.html --dist-dir development -p 3000",
  "build": "parcel build public/index.html --dist-dir dist --public-url ./",
  "prettier": "npx prettier --write **/*.html"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"description": "",
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.24.7",
  "@babel/runtime-corejs2": "^7.25.0",
  "buffer": "^6.0.3",
  "parcel": "^2.12.0",
  "prettier": "^3.3.3",
  "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.6.6",
  "process": "^0.11.10",
  "sass": "^1.77.8",
  "tailwind-classes-sorter": "^0.2.5",
  "tailwindcss": "^3.4.10"
},
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/runtime": "^7.25.0",
  "axios": "^1.7.4"
}
}

